# "Freeze" data state in an Oracle PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, select, freeze

I have a quite complicated PL/SQL procedure selecting data dynamically and multiple times. Eventually, the data is aggregated and returned.

However, due to multiple selects, the returned data might be inconsistant, because data changes might happen between the different selects. A process might look like this:

- Select data 1
- Change from a different session
- Select data 2
  --> Data 2 might now be inconsistant with data 1 due to the changes.

Unfortunately, I cannot select all data at once with a single select. This would be too complicated.

Is there a way in Oracle to somehow "freeze" the data state (not respecting any incoming changes) until the procedure is finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Oracle's [Serializable Isolation Level](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-8DA9A191-4CA3-4B1A-995F-4B17471C2738):

> In the serializable isolation level, a transaction sees only changes committed at the time the transaction—not the query—began and changes made by the transaction itself.

It is started like this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant! Thanks a lot!